# How to position a Bootstrap 3 popover to appear next to a hotspot area on an image map?

Tags: popover, imagemap

I have created an image map of a graveyard, with hotspots for each headstone, upon which I'd like to show HTML rich Bootstrap 3 popovers however when my popovers appear they appear at the top of the image as opposed to alongside the hotspot.

This is my map:

```
<img width="1200" height="930" alt="" src="http://www.nathonjoneswebdesign.co.uk/portpatrickoldkirkyard/hotspotmap/CHURCHYARDHOTSPOTMAP.jpg" usemap="#HeadstoneMap">
<map name="HeadstoneMap">
<area title="Map Reference 1" href="#" shape="poly" coords="795,299,810,299,811,322,794,322" alt="Map Reference 1" data-toggle="popover1" data-content="">
<area title="Map Reference 2" href="#" shape="poly" coords="816,247,815,270,833,269,832,246" alt="Map Reference 2" data-toggle="popover2" data-content="">
</map>
```

This is my JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('[data-toggle="popover1"]').popover({
html: true,
trigger: 'hover',
placement: 'top',
content: function(){return '<img src="http://www.nathonjoneswebdesign.co.uk/portpatrickoldkirkyard/portpatrick-headstones/M1a.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""/>';}
});

$('[data-toggle="popover2"]').popover({
html: true,
trigger: 'hover',
placement: 'top',
content: function(){return '<img src="http://www.nathonjoneswebdesign.co.uk/portpatrickoldkirkyard/portpatrick-headstones/M2a.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""/>';}
});
});
```

Here is a Bootply of the problem:
http://www.bootply.com/YvO9vRu68J

You can also view the issue on the test site at:
http://www.nathonjoneswebdesign.co.uk/portpatrickoldkirkyard/churchyard-map.php

I have only made live headstones 1 and 2, for testing purposes, which are just below the distance marker on the right.

You'll also notice that I am repeating my JavaScript for each popover however I would like, if possible, to slot that into a repeat region and populate the data from a recordset (PHP/MySQL) so that the map responds to any changes made by the user to the database records.  That may be for another post though!

Would appreciate any help offered, thank you.

NJ

EDIT: Is this beyond what Bootstrap 3 popovers / jquery / javascript can do perhaps?  Is there an alternative to image maps that I should investigate?

Comment: If I have done something to offend anyone, or have broken an etiquette that I'm clearly not aware of, then my sincere apologies.  I don't want to repeat post things though so I'd appreciate clarification on my faux pas if that is, indeed, what has happened here.  It may be, of course, that this issue is just too complex?

Comment: Hi Nathan, I don't think you offended anyone, I think you stumped them.